# What is the Mu (μ) symbol mean when looking at some time based views

Tags: java, jprofiler

When I'm profiling I can see some data with ms (for milliseconds) but I also see μs.  What does μs mean in JProfiler?

Comment: Also worth noting that `ns` is nano-second or 1/1000th of a μs. e.g. `System.nanoTime()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means microseconds, which is 1/1000th of a millisecond (1000 μs = 1 ms). The Greek letter mu (μ) is the SI prefix for [micro-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-).

Comment: Ahh, Thanks. Here's the wikipedia link for those interested. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond Is there a way to show ms for everything?

Comment: No idea about that, as I don't use JProfiler (not really a Java programmer here ;)

Comment: @DanHoward You can open the view settings (View->View settings in the menu or the corresponding tool bar button) to change the way times are displayed in JProfiler.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said it's 1000 times smaller than a millisecond, and is a standard measurement (not just for jprofiler.)

There's a nice table [here](http://www.simetric.co.uk/si_time.htm) that lists the various units, microseconds included!

Answer (score 0):

Micro seconds = 1000th of a milli second